# Что означает эта часть кода?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random

# длина блока кодирования
CHUNK_LENGTH = 8

# проверка длины блока
assert not CHUNK_LENGTH % 8, 'Длина блока должна быть кратна 8'

# вычисление контрольных бит
CHECK_BITS = [i for i in range(1, CHUNK_LENGTH + 1)if not i & (i - 1)]
print(CHECK_BITS)
```

Как работает часть кода `if not i & (i - 1)` ?
Без неё выводит [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]. С ней [1, 2, 4, 8], то есть степени двойки.
В чём логика работы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` - это операция **побитовое и**. Результат получается побитовым сравнением двух чисел, и в соответствующем бите будет `0`, если хотя бы у одного из операндов этот бит равен `0`.

Степень двойки в двоичном виде имеет представление:

```
10000...0000
```

Т.е. в старшем разряде единица, а все остальные разряды нули. При вычитании единицы (`i-1`), получается, что все биты числа меняются на противоположные. А значит **побитовое и** вернет `0` для `i & (i - 1)`, если `i` - степень двойки. Этим мы установили, что для всех степеней двойки `i & (i - 1) == 0`.

Теперь, если же `i` не степень двойки, то отнимание единицы, никогда не изменит самый старший разряд числа (т.к. это возможно только в случае если во всех остальных разрядах нули, т.е. для степени двойки). А это значит, что в двоичном представлении `i` и `(i - 1)` в старшем разряде всегда `1`, и значит, что и в `i & (i - 1)` в старшем разряде тоже `1`, т.е. `i & (i - 1) != 0`.